# MySQL how do i delete duplicate rows from very large table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to know most effective way of deleting duplicated rows from very large table, (over 1 billion rows in this table) so i need to know a very efficient way of doing this as this may take days if i execute a ineffective query.

I need to delete all duplicate urls in the search table,

i.e

```
DELETE FROM search WHERE (url) NOT IN 
(
SELECT  url FROM
(
SELECT url FROM search GROUP BY url
) X
);
```

Comment: I don't think you're likely to get different answers than the ones in the **Related** questions.

Comment: i am currently testing this answer on a test table for the performance to see how long it takes

Comment: @mahen3d: The query you propose looks like it's going to either delete every row from the table (if there no rows with a `url` value of NULL), or delete no rows (if there's any row that has a `url` value of NULL.) For a very large table, the issue isn't just total time, it's the amount of work that needs to be done (locking, logging, and rollback for InnoDB). If it's a very large percentage of rows, you might consider creating a new table, and copying just the rows from the old table you want to keep. That's usually faster, even if you have to recreate foreign keys.

Comment: @spencer7593 good idea, hmm maybe better idea to select INTO a new table with DISTINCT / GROUP BY ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends entirely on your indexes. Do this in two steps: (1) create the highest-selectivity indexes your DBMS supports on the URL field combined with any other field that can distinguish records with the same URL, such as a primary key or time stamp field; (2) write procedural code (not just a query) to process a small fraction if the records at a time and commit results in these small batches, e.g. sliced by PK mod 1000, or the 3 characters of the URL preceding the .TLD part.

This is the best way to have a predictable result, unless you are sure the DB process won't run out of memory, log file space etc. during the long cycle of deletes a straight query would require.

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE from search
where id not in (
   select min(id) from search
   group by url
   having count(*)=1

   union

   SELECT min(id) FROM search
   group by url
   having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Some explanation as to why this would help would be useful.